# Debug on Windows phone 7 DEVICE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am new to windows phone 7 development. I want to run/debug my WP7 app in connected device, when i change target to windows phone device(from windows phone emulator) in VS 2010, its unable to run and showing a error meesage. am i missing any steps/procedure.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Do you have a developer account? You need a developer account (register at https://dev.windowsphone.com, costs $100/year) in order to deploy and debug apps directly in a phone.

Comment: Just guessing the same, I thought its like android :), anyway i will register now. Thanks for support.

Comment: If you're a student and your uni have registered with DreamSpark then you can get it free for a year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can deploy an application to a Windows Phone, you must first register the phone, which requires an active developer account on Dev Center. Each developer account enables the registration of three devices for application development. After you create a developer account and your phone is registered, you can install, run, and debug unsigned applications on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

You can get 3 types of errors:

1. You device does not registered as a developer's one.
2. Zune software does not launched.
3. You phone is under the lock screen.